# Batch load google maps markerclusterer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Im using the Google Maps Marker Clusterer to build my Google Maps, which works great on smaller sets of data (up to several thousand).

Though when a data set is quite large, i.e. 10K, the browser immediately reports the script as being unresponsive and the user has to choose to let the script run. I understand that there is a lot of processing involved for a js file to do. Is there any way to batch load the results so the script is not being flooded with data and returning as unresponsive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Break your array into smaller chunks, use setTimeout to space out adding the chunks to the MarkerClusterer.